# How to return std::string from method of templated class, no matter the type?

Tags: c++, string, templates, std

I'm having a hell of a time solving what I think should be an easy thing to do.  I have a templated class, that looks something like this (has other code, to load the values, etc).  The types I'm concerned with working are char, int, bool, and std::string.

```
template <typename T>
class MyVector
{
public:
    std::string get()
    {
        return m_vector[m_current_index];                   // 1
        return std::to_string(m_vector[m_current_index]);   // 2

                                                            // 3
        if constexpr (!std::is_same_v<T, std::string>) {
            return std::to_string(m_vector[m_current_index]);
        }
        return m_vector[m_current_index];
    }

private:
    std::vector<T> m_vector;
    int m_current_index{-1};
};
```

Option (1) above fails for any typename T that is not a std::string.

Option (2) works for any typename T **except** for std::string

Option (3) doesn't appear to get actually handled at compile time (the same error occurs as in the case of option (1))

Answer (score 5):

Almost as soon as I posted, the answer jumped out at me... but perhaps this helps someone else in the future!

```
if constexpr (!std::is_same_v<T, std::string>) {
    return std::to_string(m_vector[m_current_index]);
} else {
    return m_vector[m_current_index];
}
```

The compiler isn't smart enough to ignore the 'else' case unless it's specifically within an 'else' block.

Comment: interesting observation. Note that outside of constexpr-if the code must be valid, irrespective of any `return`s before. Its similar to `void foo() { return; asdf; }` being invalid even though you could argue that `asdf;` is never reached.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 shouldn't your comment be (also)under the question?

Comment: @AKL its the same user. why should I comment twice?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818  no i know that. I said it because I got confused by reading it under the answer the first time but I found it more fitting for the question.

Comment: @AKL sorry, I dont get it. My comment refers to the answer not to the question

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I am really confused now my friend! Maybe I am getting it wrong but the situation that you illustrated can be seen in the code in the question but not in the answer!